# Getting error(identifier is undefined) in the given code

Tags: c++

I'm getting error( identifier "isEqualTo" is undefined) in the expression of the first if statement of the following code.

```
'template <typename T>
 T isEqualTo<bool>(T arg1, T arg2)
 {
  if (arg1 == arg2)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}

int main()
{
int i1 = 1, i2 = -1, i3 = 2, i4 = 4;

cout << "***  Integers Tests  ***\n";

if (isEqualTo(i1, i1))
    cout << "Integers:  " << i1 << " and " << i1 << " are equal\n";
else
    cout << "Integers:  " << i1 << " and " << i1 << " are \"Not\" equal\n";

if (isEqualTo(i3, i4))
    cout << "Integers:  " << i3 << " and " << i4 << " are equal\n";
else
    cout << "Integers:  " << i3 << " and " << i4 << " are \"Not\" equal\n";'
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

```
 template <typename T>
 T isEqualTo<bool>(T arg1, T arg2)
```

This declares a specialization of some existing template named `isEqualTo`. Unfortunately, you have not defined this template.

That is your compiler's error message, verbatim. Your `isEqualTo` template is not defined.

You have to define the template, before attempting to specialize it.

Comment: Is it possible that i'm getting this error because <bool>, because when I remove it this error is gone. But then, I get a new error in my user defined type if expression.

Comment: Yes. You shouldn't include `<bool>` here. The compiler will instantialize it and determine T from the type of the actual arguments.

Comment: when I don't include it, I get error(expression must have bool type) in my if statement, in which my arguments are objects of user defined class.

Comment: you need to create template specialization for user defined class

Comment: If you want to compare user-defined classes, your user-defined classes must have their own `operator==`, which has nothing to do with this template.